# Finding the difference in months as integers

Tags: c++

I have two vectors that represent months i.e. 1 as January 2 as February, etc... how do we find the difference between months without getting negative values?

Example

dates1 = [1, 3, 1];

dates2 = [12, 1, 0];

Expected: dates2 - dates1 = [11, 10, 11]

Actual: [11, -2, -1]

Comment: What seems to be the problem? What gives you negative values?

Comment: @Snorrlaxxx I would suggest looking into modular arithmetic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have two months `a` and `b`, and `b` is after `a`, and `b` may possibly be in the following year, you can just use something like:

```
diff = (b + 12 - a) % 12;
```

The adding of twelve to `b` ensures that it is greater than `a` (effectively moving it into the following year) and the use of modulo ensures the adding of twelve doesn't move it *two* years beyond `a`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use modulo arithmetic:

```
const int MONTHS_PER_YEAR = 12;
int difference = ((month_1 + MONTHS_PER_YEAR) - month_2) % MONTHS_PER_YEAR;
```